# How to display selected text of a dropdown menu and dynamically populate it from an array of strings?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, jsp

I have a dropdown menu using twitter bootstrap. I want to-

a) **Dynamically populate it from an array of strings which I fetch from my database.**

b) **Display the selected text of the dropdown as replacing the default dropdown text.**

How do I do this?

My current code for the dropdown menu is as follows:

```
 <div class="btn-group" role="group">
     <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
            Dropdown
  <span class="caret"></span>
        </button>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
          <li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

Comment: Please do not simply downvote. Please help out, or if you need more details, just ask.

Comment: How are you retrieving the data? Are you familiar with javascript or jquery? I would imagine it got down voted simply because it is a very basic question missing a lot of relevant information needed to provide an answer or help.

Comment: I have a method in my java file which, upon call, fetches the list of some values from a database. I am thinking of linking this to my above code using an action, but I m stuck as to how to dynamically populate my dropdown menu.

Comment: I am new to javasript/ jquery. Is there a way to do this in my jsp file containing the above mentioned code enclosing it within <% %> instead?

Comment: I'm not familiar with jsp, but assuming the array is available to javascript, it's pretty simple.  You're using bootstrap, which means you already have jQuery included, and that can make quick work of it. I can make a fiddle...

Answer (score 2):

Here's an [example fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/p9bfu7jd/). I made the assumption that the array of strings is available to javascript/jQuery.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var myData = ['Option 1','Option 2','Option 3','Option 4'], //your array
        myItemList = $('#myDropdown .dropdown-menu');//ref to dd list 

    //clear contents of existing dropdown
    myItemList.html('');

    //iterate array and create dropdown links
    $(myData).each(function(index, element){
        var item = ('<li><a href="#">'+element+'</a></li>');
        myItemList.append(item);
    });


    //handler to change the text of the dropdown button
    $('#myDropdown').on('click', 'a', function(e){
        var setText = $(e.currentTarget).text(),
            newHtml = setText + '&nbsp;<span class="caret"></span>';
        $('#myDropdown > button').html(newHtml);
    });
});
```

HTH,

-Ted

Comment: But where and how exactly to place this with respect to my code in my jsp page?

Comment: That's where I become less useful... all that would need to be wrapped in a doc ready function: `$(document).ready(function(){the code here});`, but i'm not familiar enough with jsp to tell you where html scripts should go. I edited the answer to add the doc ready function

Comment: You may find [this page](http://mrbool.com/how-to-use-javascript-in-jsp/29895) helpful

Comment: Thanks for the help. I will surely check this out.